# TV show where a boy's bracelet signals his soulmate is a girl from a lower social class that is disapproved by his well-off family

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm seeking the name of the TV show this episode must have been a part of. The episode starts with the parents going on about how the time has come for the bracelet their son is wearing to find his soul mate.

As the show progresses, the boy gets an alarm as he gets close to a young lady that the family would never have let him choose as they see her family as a lower class. The boy's family is clearly well off, but the girl's family are servants.

Unfortunately, that's all I saw, as it was only in a YouTube short.

Comment: You mean the Youtube short was the show or it was a clip from the show?

Comment: You could check your history, find the YouTube short again and read the comments. Maybe someone identified it there.Checking out other videos posted by the same person might also help.

Comment: Thank you for making this question clearer for the reader @galacticninja. I am far better at the spoken word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the movie [*TiMER*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timer_(film)) (2009). The conceit is that people can choose to be fitted with a countdown timer that goes to zero when they meet their soulmate.

Jesse (a white kid with well-off parents) meets Soledad (the daughter of the family's gardener, Eduardo), and their [respective timers go off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY7fpDQlFc8&t=34s), indicating that they're soulmates.

[image: relevant clip of the movie]

Comment: For the record, I suspect that I saw the same short film as you. They edited it and added a voiceover that added some details that weren't in the film, such as that you only get a warning that you're going to meet your soulmate *that day* and that it chimes when you've locked eyes with them.

Comment: Thank you for the near immediate response, I am grateful.

Comment: @Vethor - I'm still on the hunt for the actual clip on tiktok or youtube with the edited version of this.